# Looking for list of files already included with each version of Windows (XP, Vista, 7) so we know what to distribute

Tags: windows-vista, windows-xp, window

We have been distributing OleAut32.dll and olepro32.dll (and other DLLs that are in the [VB6 Runtime package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887))  for many years now but Windows 7 has a newer version of those. And we were forcing our VB6 app to use *our* copies of them.

I removed all of our standard DLL's (including the above) and the app runs just fine, so they're all included with Windows 7.  And it looks like we just need the newer version of OleAut32.dll (if reinstall the app and replace OleAut32.dll with the new one from Win 7 it works fine)

It occurs to me that some of those files (like even the msVBvm60.dll) come pre-installed  so we're much better off just not installing those files.  (Or we may have to bite the bullet and do it the old fashioned way (:-) and install to the system and use version checking.  It's been nice to not have any DLL hell for the last 10 years or so. But I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's Microsoft's **[list of the VB6 runtime files shipped with Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx)**  7 (and Vista and Windows Server 2008). It includes all the core VB6 runtime files, like oleaut32.dll and msvbvm60.dll.

Microsoft also has a list of [Controls that shipped with VB6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194784) and the corresponding DLL/OCX dependencies.